# Adapt parameters to minimise RMSE

Tags: matlab

I have a model of the height profile of an ice sheet. I have an array with the observed height as a function of the distance x (`sur_obs`), and a model output of the same variables, which is calculated as:

```
for i=2:xnum+1
    H=2000;
    L=350000;
    sur(i)=(H*(sqrt(1-(x(i)/L))));
end
```

I now want to find the combination of H and L values so that the RMSE of the observed and modeled profile is minimal (`n=35`). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic optimization problem. You can use [Gradient Descent](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2654-netlab/content/graddesc.m), but there are a whole bunch of solutions. Check [optimization by matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/optimization.html).